# Find all nodes in tree, without a sibling

Tags: java, tree

> Find all nodes of trees, without siblings.

This question is attributed to [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-dont-sibling-binary-tree/).

I'm looking for code reviews, optimizations and best practices.

```
  public class PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<T> {

        private TreeNode<T> root;

        public PrintNodesWithoutSiblings(List<T> items) { 
            create(items);
        }

        private void create (List<T> items) {
            root = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(0));

            final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
            queue.add(root);

            final int half = items.size() / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
                if (items.get(i) != null) {
                    final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();
                    int left = 2 * i + 1;
                    int right = 2 * i + 2;

                    if (items.get(left) != null) {
                        current.left = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(left));
                        queue.add(current.left);
                    }
                    if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                        current.right = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(right));
                        queue.add(current.right);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static class TreeNode<T> {
            private TreeNode<T> left;
            private T item;
            private TreeNode<T> right;

            TreeNode(T item) {
                this.item = item;
            }
        }


        public List<T> nonSiblingNodes() {
            if (root == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Empty tree. Tree cannot be empty.");
            }

            final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
            findNonSiblingNodes(root, list);
            return list;
        } 


        private void findNonSiblingNodes(TreeNode<T> node, List<T> list) {
            if (node == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
                findNonSiblingNodes(node.left, list);
                findNonSiblingNodes(node.right, list);
            } else if (node.left != null) {
                list.add(node.left.item);
                findNonSiblingNodes(node.left, list);
            } else if (node.right != null) {
                list.add(node.right.item);
                findNonSiblingNodes(node.right, list);
            }
        }
    }


    public class PrintNodesWithoutSiblingTest {


        @Test
        public void test1() {
            PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer> ps1 = new PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, null));
            assertTrue(Arrays.asList(4, 6).equals(ps1.nonSiblingNodes()));
        }

        @Test
        public void test2() {
            PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer> ps2 = new PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 4, null, null, null));
            assertTrue(Arrays.asList(2, 4).equals(ps2.nonSiblingNodes()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Recursion

The null-check in your recursive method is redundant. The preliminary checks and the mid-recursion checks ensure that the method is never called with a null input.

I also really favour a simplified recursive approach, where the recursion checks it's own conditions, instead of pre-checking the recursive conditions before calling the recursion. In this case, it halves the number of recursive calls, halves the list.adds, and reduces by a third the number of if-conditions in your code:

```
    private void findNonSiblingNodes(TreeNode<T> node, boolean hasSibling List<T> list) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!hasSibling) {
            list.add(node);
        }

        findNonSiblingNodes(node.left, node.right != null, list);
        findNonSiblingNodes(node.right, node.left != null, list);
    }
```

You would call that code with:

```
    public List<T> nonSiblingNodes() {
        final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        findNonSiblingNodes(root, true, list);
        return list;
    } 
}
```

It is safe to remove the null-check on the root node, because it can never be null at that point. That's because ....

### Bugs

... your code does horrible things in the constructor, which will fail before it gets here:

```
    public PrintNodesWithoutSiblings(List<T> items) { 
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<T> items) {
        root = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(0));
        ....
```

Your constructor will throw NPE if the items is null, and will throw NoSuchElementException if the List is empty. Thus, the root will never be null in the recursion.

### Style

> ```
> final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
> ```

You should use the 'diamond operator' when using Java7 and later. The line above can be just:

```
final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Similarly, the line:

> ```
> final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
> ```

can be:

```
final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 7):

## Data Structures vs. Methods to operate on them

A pattern I commonly see in your code is that whenever you're supposed to do an *operation on a tree*, you end up *implementing the tree* plus adding the operation itself.

Your code would be a lot simplified if you re-used the same data structures. For this code assignment, I would like to see your code as:

```
public static List<T> findNonSiblingNodes(BinaryTree<T> tree) {
    ... perform operations and return results ...
}
```

This would force you to do proper **separation of concerns**, which adheres to the **single responsibility principle**.

It would also greatly **reduce bugs in your code** because of **reduced code duplication** and *not have us mention some things over and over again*.

As an example of code duplication, compare your `create` method in the code you have for this question with your `create` method in [Given a BST, transform it into greater sum tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55966/given-a-bst-transform-it-into-greater-sum-tree), and in [Detect if a tree is a complete binary tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55626/detect-if-a-tree-is-complete-binary-tree). **It is the same code!** All of these assignments would greatly benefit from using a shared `BinaryTree` (or `BinarySearchTree`) implementation.

I like that you in this code have made `TreeNode` generic with `TreeNode<T>`, this is a great start for a shared `BinaryTree` implementation.

*If you need any help with this, or want suggestions on how to structure your code/projects, don't be afraid to drop by in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). We don't bite.*

Comment: "A pattern I commonly see in your code is that whenever you're supposed to do an operation on a tree, you end up implementing the tree plus adding the operation itself. " - Since I am practicing for interviews, most of the answers are tailored to how I would write on white board. Thus in any interview round there would be 1 question of tree, at one point in time, on the white board. Thus resusability works in real life wont work for interviews.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Sure, but if you get this question at an interview, it would not make that good impression to make it in the same class and name it like you do. Besides, once you actually get the job (or a job) then you are faced with real life so it is a good idea to practice it. It's still important with separation of concerns.

Comment: I understand, but on the other hand I have also seen Linkedlist.java do the same, and I want to replicate that. I would say you had a good feedback, and I see great advantages but just opting the other way. Thanks

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I fail to see the connection between what you're doing and `LinkedList.java`. The `LinkedList` **is** a data structure, what you're mostly implementing is methods that are supposed to do work **on** a data structure.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper The choice is yours, it is your code. Just remember that *if you keep doing what you have always done, you will get the same results that you have always gotten.*

Comment: Let me explain my thinking - each code is an independent piece as mentioned, becuase in interview ( not in real life ) i have to write linkedlist or tree only once on white-board so I guess code duplication concern can be discarded.

Comment: Regarding second feedback - just liked linkedlist has operations such as 'remove' or 'add' or stack has operations such as 'push' or 'pop' I am adding additional functionality to 'merge' or 'findsiblings'. Its a fine line between what you want to implement as an object method of Collections class with static method. I am not sure. Maybe you are right.

Comment: Thirdly if I do what you say, then I can no longer have 'Node' or 'TreeNode' as private static class, since operations such as node.left or node.right, cannot be done if I keep Node/TreeNode as private static nested class. And hiding internal details is recommended.

Answer (score 6):

### Tests

I will say it again and again and again! Tests are **important**!! Don't throw 2 tests that are, sorry to say it, really bad. You should use them like powerful tools that will help you create better code. If you don't put effort on them, then don't bother to make them.

```
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer> ps1 = new PrintNodesWithoutSiblings<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6,  null));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(4, 6).equals(ps1.nonSiblingNodes()));
    }
```

`test1` is really a bad name. I've already point it out in other [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55714), so I will not extend on that. But you've added a new things here, you used `assertTrue()` to test the equality of the two lists. Why? You've already used `assertEquals`, why would you not use it? Since what you really want is to verify that those lists are equal.

There is nothing more to say for those tests than what I've already said in my previous answer. Add more tests, do them carefully and put the same effort that you would for your algo.

Comment: [Always use .equals() to determine equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201944)